# Omit a row with bad data from SQL query results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am querying a column that should be an integer, but was set up as varchar, and in one row out of 800k+ someone managed to sneak a letter in there. I am trying to run a query that compares the values of that column, but I can't cast to integer because of the one bad value.

```
SELECT newtable.* FROM (
  SELECT
    LIAB_ID, LIAB_STATUS, LIAB_PERIOD
    
    WHERE (LIAB_STATUS = 'CURRENT')
    AND LIAB_PERIOD not like '202O120'  -- that's the letter O and not a zero
  )
AS newtable
WHERE cast(LIAB_PERIOD as INT) < 2023031
```

How can I adjust my query to skip over the one bad row and let me query the rest of the data as though `LIAB_PERIOD` is an integer?

Comment: With `TRY_CAST()`.

Comment: Use `try_convert / try_cast`

Comment: Why not fix the one value (and then fix the column)?

Comment: @Stuckat1337 I don't have access to edit or update the table.

Comment: You should tell someone who does have that access, because this is a fundamental design flaw that will continue to cause these issues for everyone who touches that column...

Comment: @AaronBertrand absolutely right. We're in the process of converting to a new system and this error will get validated out. For now all I can do is hunt and peck for these kinds of issues.

Comment: It shouldn't be "validated out" @nickfindley , the column should never be a `varchar` in the first place if it's meant to be a numerical value. An `int` *can't* store an invalid integer; it's not a validating thing.

Comment: @ThomA correct, I'm just using bad terminology. The column actually represents a date (2020120 = 2020-12-31) and in the new system it will actually be a date field instead of a varchar. We're just working with what we have in the old system right now.

Answer (score -1):

Reading through the comments it sounds like you are preparing to migrate this data to a new or upgraded application.  It seems like listing all of the errant rows would be more helpful at this stage in your upgrade/migration:

```sql
SELECT LIAB_ID
, LIAB_STATUS
, LIAB_PERIOD

WHERE LIAB_STATUS = 'CURRENT'
  AND ISNUMERIC(LIAB_PERIOD) <> 1
```

Then you have the application owner or users go in a fix what can be fixed before moving on.  The specific problem you mention would be very simple to fix.  A couple users focused on this for a day could easily fix a few thousand errors.  Better yet, for those that have errors similar to what you show in your question -- an O in place of a 0 -- you could fix them automatically.